# Swift access textfield value in one tableviewcell from another tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am not sure if this is a strange setup but I have two custom tableView cells -

1. PhoneCell
2. EmailCell

In PhoneCell, I have two text fields with some values in those textFields. In EmailCell, I have one textField.

I need to access the values of those two textFields available in PhoneCell, in my EmailCell now. And, this PhoneCell can be added four times i.e. I can add four phone numbers

Is it possible, how do I implement this?

Ultimately, I am trying to do below -

1. Get textField values in PhoneCell (maximum of 4 numbers) to EmailCell
2. To a button action in EmailCell (`saveContactDataClicked`), I need to make a service call with phoneCell textfield data and emailCell textField data together as POST request.

**PhoneCell**

```
class PhoneCell: ProfileCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var countryCode: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var addPhoneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var teleNumber: UITextField! 

override func configure(withUser user: UserData, language: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    super.configure(withUser: user, language: language, indexPath: indexPath)

    if user.phones?.count == 0 {
        self.countryCode.text = ""
        self.teleNumber.text = ""
    }

    else {
        if let userPhoneInfo = user.phones {

            self.countryCode.text = userPhoneInfo[indexPath.row].country
            self.teleNumber.text = userPhoneInfo[indexPath.row].number

        }
    }
}


}
```

I am trying like this from **EmailCell** but can't get the textField values in phoneCell

```
class EmailCell: ProfileCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var cautionLabel: UILabel!        

    @IBOutlet weak var cautionTextView: UITextView!       

    @IBAction func saveContactDataClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

        let phoneCell = PhoneCell()

        let phoneCode = phoneCell.countryCode.text
        let phoneNumber = phoneCell.teleNumber.text

        let data = ContactInfoData(phoneCode: phoneCode!,
                                   phoneNumber: phoneNumber!,
                                   emailAddress: emailText.text!)

        delegate?.saveEdits(forContactInfoCell: self, withData: data)
    }

    override func configure(withUser user: UserData, language: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        super.configure(withUser: user, language: language, indexPath: indexPath)

        emailText.text = user.email

    }
```

Comment: You should declare your emailCell in phoneViewController and then you can access its value in phoneViewContrller. You shouldn't do those actions in customCell class. It is for view not to control things.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp: Ok, you mean, I should implement the saveButtonAction from my ViewController instead of from the cell?

Comment: Which viewcontroller does these cell belong? You should work with data, not the view

Comment: That is right. :)

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp: ok. I believe that's the only way out. Because I have data from two different cells? So I depend on the view controller. Hmm.. correct me if I am wrong please

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should declare your `emailCell` in `phoneViewController` and then you can access its value in `phoneViewContrller`. You shouldn't do those actions in `customCell` class. It is for view not to control things.

In `phoneViewController` make `cellForRowAt indexPath` functions and declare 2 cells like this:

```
let phoneCell: phoneCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "phoneCell") as! PhoneCell
let emailCell: emailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emailCell") as! EmailCell
```

And now you can access your textField value like this:

```
let phoneCode = emailCell.countryCode.text
let phoneNumber = emailCell.teleNumber.text
```

You can do it upside down also. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Yes, I have this implemented already in my ViewController. But was just trying to see if I can make it work from my cell directly. Which is a learning for me now that I better do it in my ViewController, and not in the cell.

Comment: Ohh.. Okay, then it is good. If you want to learn more, you should google about Model View Controller. This is the principle you should follow. However if I understand you correct, you now can access the textField value as you want?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the textField values now. But I am stuck on a different issue now. :| May be I should post it as a new question in SO

Answer (score 0):

You can get values of textyfield by assigning **tag** to each **textfield** also.

```
if let txtField1 = self.view.viewWithTag(someTag) as? UITextField {

        print(txtField1.text!)

}
```